# Vega Lite bar exceeds limits

Tags: vega-lite

I created a three way graph with a map a histogram and a bar chart that looks like this:

[image]
These graphs are connected with a select function for each. If you click on the county bar chart it will reflect on the map and the histogram, however when I do so the histogram bars exceed the graph:

[image]
Is there a way to stop this?
Secondly, I have a selection based on sex, where if you click on the "sex" in the legend it will just give that sex. When I added the other selections that part stopped working:

```
      [1

]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYOWK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNNXV.png

Just wondering if anyone has any idea how to solve these issues.
```

Comment: Without more information it will be difficult to answer your question. Please include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: added some more have to delete later though.

Comment: @jakevdp readded the pictures as well

Comment: @jakevdp any thoughts?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Vega-Lite. I would report it at http://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues

Comment: Oh the exceeding of the bars or the issue with selection on legend of Sex?

Comment: The first – sorry, I didn't even see that second question. In the future please try to limit your posts to asking a single question.